# CSS3 transition makes background disappear and changes colors

Tags: css, colors, background, transform, transition

OK, I have a big problem here..
I am creating a new website with CSS3 effects http://sauldesign.com/vtdk/ . When I wrote a css code for main title 3D effect (Roll), other website parts have broken - backgrounds of #index3 and #index4 disappeared and all colors of background images changed to little lighter and brighter.

When you scroll to #index3 part you see black background (there should be an image). You can see the real background image appear when #index3 is almost scrolled out of the view to the top (bg image appears when #index3 bottom is about 100px from top).

When I delete all css3 transition and transform code, everything works fine. Here is css3 code:

```
    /* CSS3 ROLL LINKS */

.main-title {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
    -webkit-transition: all 400ms ease;
       -moz-transition: all 400ms ease;
        -ms-transition: all 400ms ease;
            transition: all 400ms ease;

    -webkit-perspective: 300px;
       -moz-perspective: 300px;
        -ms-perspective: 300px;
            perspective: 300px;

    -webkit-perspective-origin: 50% 50%;
       -moz-perspective-origin: 50% 50%;
        -ms-perspective-origin: 50% 50%;
            perspective-origin: 50% 50%;
}
.main-title:hover {
    background: none;
    text-shadow: none;

    -webkit-transition: all 600ms ease;
       -moz-transition: all 400ms ease;
        -ms-transition: all 400ms ease;
            transition: all 400ms ease;

    -webkit-transform: scale(0.85,0.85);
       -moz-transform: scale(0.85,0.85);
        -ms-transform: scale(0.85,0.85);
            transform: scale(0.85,0.85);
}
.main-title span {
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    padding: 10px 30px;
    pointer-events: none;
    background-color: #fff;

    -webkit-transition: all 600ms ease;
       -moz-transition: all 400ms ease;
        -ms-transition: all 400ms ease;
            transition: all 400ms ease;

    -webkit-transform-origin: 50% 0%;
       -moz-transform-origin: 50% 0%;
        -ms-transform-origin: 50% 0%;
            transform-origin: 50% 0%;

    -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
       -moz-transform-style: preserve-3d;
        -ms-transform-style: preserve-3d;
            transform-style: preserve-3d;
}
.main-title:hover span {
    background: #fff;

    -webkit-transform: translate3d( 0px, 0px, -45px ) rotateX( 90deg );
       -moz-transform: translate3d( 0px, 0px, -45px ) rotateX( 90deg );
        -ms-transform: translate3d( 0px, 0px, -45px ) rotateX( 90deg );
            transform: translate3d( 0px, 0px, -45px ) rotateX( 90deg );
}
.main-title span:after {
    content: attr(data-title);

    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    padding: 10px 30px;
    white-space: nowrap;

    color: #2366ac;
    background: #fff; 

    -webkit-transform-origin: 50% 0%;
       -moz-transform-origin: 50% 0%;
        -ms-transform-origin: 50% 0%;
            transform-origin: 50% 0%;

    -webkit-transform: translate3d( 0px, 100%, 0px ) rotateX( -90deg );
       -moz-transform: translate3d( 0px, 100%, 0px ) rotateX( -90deg );
        -ms-transform: translate3d( 0px, 100%, 0px ) rotateX( -90deg );
            transform: translate3d( 0px, 100%, 0px ) rotateX( -90deg );
}
```

Comment: did you ever figure this out? i'm seeing the same types of odd issues with colors

Comment: If you post HTML code too, and (better) a jsFiddle.... maybe we can help you! :-)